# How can I find the roots of x^2+px+q=0 by using contractive mapping theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

Basically, Contractive mapping theorem guarantees that if F is contractive on some interval, then there exists a unique fixed point.

However, $x^2+px+q=0$ has two different solutions as long as $p^2>4q$

Either two roots are negative, or one is positive and the other is negative.

In this case, how can I generalize the intervals for each root ?

I considered this function $f(x)=-\frac{q}{p+x}$

And $f'(x)= \frac{q}{(p+x)^2} $

This is exactly where I am stuck

Comment: Please use MathJax in the future when writing posts, especially those with simple formulas. For a reference, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I have submitted an edit to clean up your formulas a bit. I always recommend having cleaning formulas as it encourages more people to look at your post, potentially lowering response time.

Comment: Why do you exclude the case when both roots are positive like $(x-1)(x-2)$?